# Prevent Chrome Extension uninstallation on kiosk machine

Tags: windows, google-chrome

My company has Chrome with our custom extension running on Windows machines.

Our goal is to launch Chrome locally on our machines **with our extension running at all times**. Our users are constantly looking to uninstall our extension.

Our current approach is to utilize the [ExtensionInstallForceList](https://sites.google.com/site/lock5stat/offline-use/installing-for-all-users) registry key. This *sort of* works:

[image]

Right now, one can still click into `C:\WM_0.0` and delete the folder. Once the folder is deleted, this extension is gone.

So we tried the following:

1. Create a Windows account `Client`
2. Assign `Client` to `Client Group`
3. Change the permission `C:\WM_0.0` to `Deny Write`
4. Log out and login to the machine again as `Client`.

Once I login to my Windows machine as `Client`, I can no longer load my extension:

[image]

I tried to change the folder's permission to `Full Control` for both `Users` and `Client Group` but I am still seeing this error in Chrome.

### 1. How can I load this extension successfully given my current set of circumstances?

### 2. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "Our users are constantly looking to uninstall our extension." Sounds like a fun extension! - So basically what you are looking for, is a way to load the application, but users should not be able to change files/data in any way? 1. Someone who tries answering your question needs more details regarding the system. See [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172532/can-we-tamper-proof-a-game-thats-sold-along-with-the-windows-machine-it-runs-on) question. Maybe it even answers your problem.

Comment: Companies successfully use Policies to do exactly this sort of thing. It's not a security issue, but probably appropriate on SU.

Comment: If it's a Kiosk machine, why do the users have access to files in C:\ ?!